# Make a word in TextVew clickable

Tags: android, textview, sqliteopenhelper, clickable, clickablespan

I am developing a dictionary app. When I search some keyword it will display its description. Now I want if any keyword (of my database) is used in describing other keyword I want that describing keyword to be clickable (and coloured or/and underlined). So that if I click on that word search will be made using the clicked keyword and will display the result. I am using SQLitedatabase to create database. Please see the attached picture.

Sample picture:
[image: Sample picture]

Answer (score 0):

You can use spans to style your text shown on a textview. There is a span subclass called ClickableSpan, which will be able to serve your needs. Takea a look at [ClickableSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html) also there is another span class called [UnderlineSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/UnderlineSpan.html) which can be used for putting underline for the specified character range. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank for your response. That's ok, but I want only those words clickable which exist in my database as keyword. For that what should I do?

Comment: format those words using ClickableSpan, It has a onClicked(View) callback on the span. So only the ClickableSpan formatted words will be clickable

Comment: My database is created when my app is starting for the first time (i.e. during installation) and reading from a .txt file through a bufferedReader. Would you please show me some sample, I don't have any idea how to do that.